# Previewing PHP files within Subversion?

Tags: php, svn

So after our codebase had become unmanageable, we finally decided to set up subversion for a web project I work on with a few friends.  We've successfully set up a trunk and branches for each developer.  We're working with PHP.  What I'm wondering is, is if there's any way to actually view a PHP file's output from within Subversion so that when one of the other developers checks in a change, I can browse to his branch in my browser and then see what the site would look like and test his changes before merging with the trunk?  Right now, if I browse to another developer's branch, all I see is the PHP source code in the browser window.

Is this possible without checking out/exporting every time?  Are we going about this the wrong way?  Any insight is greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The usual way is the other way round: You test changes in a live environment, then check them in as defined changesets. Having a live environment somehow directly connected to a repository sounds difficult to do, and wrong to my ears.

A better way of going about this IMO would be testing changes locally, checking them in, and having a deployment mechanism that checks out the latest revision of the application, and installs it somewhere to browse. If your application's configurtation is built well, it's easy to set this up in a way so you can browse specific revisions using different URLs. I would keep this totally separate from subversion though.

Maybe these questions can give some inspiration:

- [**Setting up a development server**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314088/setting-up-a-development-server/)
- [**Setting up a deployment / build / CI cycle for PHP projects**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180460/setting-up-a-deployment-build-ci-cycle-for-php-projects)

Comment: +1 — also worth pointing out that a local web server will allow you [@kenny] to test changes by simply updating your working copy or switching to a different branch.